# Как реализовать раздачу прав доступа в программе?

Tags: c#, mysql, алгоритм, acl

Добрый день!
На текущий момент реализована следующая схема:
В MySQL хранится 4 таблицы:

- `user` - таблица с данными пользователя.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id_User` INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`Login` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,`Password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,`Surname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,`Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,`Patronymic` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,`Mail` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL
    ,`Phone` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,`dep` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`Roles` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0|`
    ,`Groups` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0|`
    ,`Access` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0|`
    ,`Access_block` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0|`
    ,PRIMARY KEY (`id_User`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 37 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Данные записаны след. образом:

```
INSERT INTO `user`
VALUES (
    '1'
    ,'Иванов И.И.'
    ,'18ae6e16fdf5397b18bb36020755ed84'
    ,'Иванов'
    ,'Иван'
    ,'Иванович'
    ,'email@gmail.com'
    ,'666-66-66'
    ,'4'
    ,'0|'
    ,'1|2|'
    ,'0|'
    ,'0|'
    );
```

- `access_rights` - таблица с правами доступа

```
CREATE TABLE `access_rights` (
    `id` INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,`Description` VARCHAR(2500) NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (
        `id`
        ,`Name`
        )
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 18 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Данные записаны след. образом:

```
INSERT INTO `access_rights`
VALUES (
    '7'
    ,'Журнал регистрации'
    ,'Просмотр журнала регистрации'
    );
```

- `roles` - таблица ролей

```
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
    `id` INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,`Description` VARCHAR(2500) NOT NULL
    ,`id_access_rights` VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (
        `id`
        ,`Name`
        )
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 6 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 ROW_FORMAT = COMPACT;
```

Данные записаны след. образом:

```
INSERT INTO `roles`
VALUES (
    '1'
    ,'Администратор'
    ,'Администратор'
    ,'1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|16|17|0|'
    );
```

- `groups` - таблица групп

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
    `id` INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,`description` VARCHAR(2500) NOT NULL
    ,`id_roles` VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (
        `id`
        ,`Name`
        )
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 6 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Данные записаны след. образом:

```
INSERT INTO `groups`
VALUES (
    '1'
    ,'САдмины'
    ,'Администратор у которого есть доступ ко всему'
    ,'1|2|'
    );
```

По запросу через WCF передаю все права пользователя клиенту для прорисовки интерфейса программы, Согласно назначенным группам, ролям и правам доступа из таблицы user.
Схема не идеальная, просьба подсказать как ее (схему) привести к идеалу.
Либо подсказать новую схему если она идеальная.

Поделитесь информацией у кого как организованы данные схемы.

p.s. Информация для параноиков, что права можно подменить: клиенту права доступа отдаю только для прорисовки интерфейса, при выполнении функций идет проверка прав доступа на стороне сервера (WCF).

Comment: Будут какие-то критерии идеальности?

Comment: Скорость работы...

Comment: привяжите права к ролям, а не пользователям, и рисуйте интерфейс исходя из роли пользователя, или набора ролей. И еще, не стоит хранить все права в одном поле списком, попробуйте написать запрос на получение списка пользователей имеющих конкретное право и поймете почему. Лучше использовать стандартную схему с таблицами связей многие-ко-многим, права-роли, пользователи-роли, пользователи-права (это уже избыточно, но если возможен случай выдачи пользователю эксклюзивных прав не включенных в роль, будет полезно)

Comment: К тому же не достаточно информации для предложения конкретной схемы. Пользователь может иметь одну или много ролей, состоять в одной или нескольких группах? Права могут назначаться пользователю, группе, роли? Роли имеют предустановленные права?  Права группы или роли (при их наличии) замещают права пользователя, роли, группы или расширяют их? Есть ли иерархия в ролях и группах? Это краткий список вопросов, то что первое в голову пришло.

Comment: На текущее время реализована и работает схема: группа-роль-пользователь. Но так же дополнительно разработана схема: роль-пользователь и права-пользователь для более гибкой настройки прав доступа (на текущий момент не используется).
У пользователя может быть n групп, в группе может быть m ролей, а в роли может быть k прав. Иерархия на текущий момент не реализована - но требуется в будущем (спасибо за подсказку, сразу не учел этот момент).

Comment: Таблицы с группами/ролями/правами буду приводить ко 2НФ т.к. уже столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами в обработке информации.

Comment: Ну вот от этого уже можно оттолкнуться. Сейчас набросаю эскиз схемы

Comment: Перенесите уточнения из комментария в вопрос, для этого есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/633418/edit)

Answer (score 1):

**users**
user_id,
parent_id, --для поддержки иерархии пользователей
user_name

**groups**
group_id,
parent_id, --для поддержки иерархии групп
group_name

**roles**
role_id,
parent_id, --для поддержки иерархии ролей
role_name

**grants:**
grant_id,
garnt_name

**group_roles** --связь групп с ролями
group_id,
role_id

**user_roles** --связь пользователей с ролями
user_id,
role_id

**user_groups** --связь пользователей с группами
user_id,
group_id

**role_grants** --связь ролей с правами
user_id,
grant_id

**user_grants** --связь пользователей с правами
user_id,
grant_id

Вот как-то так, почти классический вариант. Единственный недостаток - таблицы связи довольно быстро растут, особенно если имеется дублирование информации, например перенос прав роли пользователю, при назначении роли, это избыточно и вместо ожидаемого прироста скорости, который можно заметить в начале, приводит к ее катастрофическому снижению в дальнейшем.

Для нормальной работы обязательно правильно настроить индексы исходя из особенностей использования. Это касается таблицы **users** и особенно  таблиц **user_roles** и **user_grants**, т.к. эти таблицы будут увеличиваться постоянно, в отличие от остальных, размер которых не меняется, изменениями размеров на этапе разработки можно пренебречь. В принципе, при правильном обращении такая схема обеспечивает линейный и прогнозируемый рост этих таблиц.

Также будет полезно настроить каскадные связи, чтобы при удалении любого основного элемента удалялись и все его связи, но это уже на любителя и по требованиям задачи.

Аналогичным образом можно реализовать привязку администраторов групп и ролей к соответствующим объектам и прочие особенности вашей системы если понадобится.

В некоторых случаях схема может быть частично денормализована, однако этим стоит заниматься только при реальной необходимости, когда все хотелки будут реализованы и выявятся все возможные связи между объектами.

Answer (score 0):

Реализовать можно так
Создать табличку пользователей, Табличку должностей. Каждого пользователя разместить по должностям. Если у пользователя нет должности, то ему вообще все закрыто. Далее создаем табличку ролей, а к табличке ролей табличку грантов. Гранты можете уже привязать к вашим элементам интерфейса или еще чего угодно. Если роль не имеет грантов, то ей тоже все закрыто. Ну и связываем должности с ролями...